# bluetooth not working hp ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hp

The bluetooth is working on windows, however it doesn't work in ubuntu 20.04. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Check if bluetooth is soft-blocked by the system. `rfkill` can help you figure it out and probably fix it too.

1. Open command prompt by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
2. Type `rfkill` and press enter, you will get output as below.

```
 ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

Now, if you see `locked` in the SOFT coloumn, you need to run the command to unblock it.

Type `rfkill unblock all` in the commant prompt.

If the bluetooth device is hard blocked, you either need to switch it on from the `BIOS` or need to check your device for damage.

Comment: rfkill doesn't show bluetooth. AND bluetooth DO work in windows 10!